# Append file names to the end of lines

Tags: python, bash, perl, sed, fasta

I have many fasta files and want to append name of files to the end of lines (header line). I know how to do it 1 by 1 by sed but looking for a better solution to do for many files.

```
File1.txt
>1
ACGTA

File2.txt
>2
GTCA
```

What expected:

```
File1.txt
>1_File1
ACGTA

File2.txt
>2_File2
GTCA
```

This works for a single file using sed in OSX:

```
sed -i.bak '/>.*$/ s/$/_File1/' File1.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple for loop:

```
for f in *.txt; do
   sed -i '' 's/^>.*/&_'"${f%.*}"'/' "$f"
done
```

`"${f%.*}"` will strip extension from filenames.

Comment: it can be even shorter:
    sed -i 's/^>.*/&_'${_.*}'/' *.txt

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the expression depending on your file names, but basically you want to iterate through all the files

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for file in *.txt
    do
      #just for echo the current 'file' var for testing
      echo "$file"
      sed -i.bak '/>.*$/ s/$/_"$file"/' $file
    done
```

Comment: After changing _"$file" to _'$file' it did a job but keep the extension of file on the line. Would be nice to exclude the extension of file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl's inplace editing capabilities:

```
perl -i.bak -p0e '$ARGV =~ s/\..*//; s/>.*/$&_$ARGV/' File*.txt
```

Comment: This didn't change anything! Thanks for suggestion though!